# 'the English grammar” vs. “∅ English grammar”

Tags: word-choice, articles, definite-article, zero-article

Which article should I use if I want to say, for example:

> Let's discuss/Let's talk about (the) English/Russian grammar.

Is the definite article “the” needed here or not?

Answer (score 3):

The definite article is definitely NOT required, as stated by the previous commenter, and is actually more common and natural without it, i.e. **Let's discuss Russian grammar**. The use of the definite article here is not incorrect, however it is superfluous and awkward, at least to my ear.

In another context, one would say: **I'm having trouble with Russian grammar**. If one said *the* Russian grammar here, it would call to mind the grammar *textbook*, since this is also called *a grammar*.

Also note the following:  Let's discuss...

- Russian pronunciation, BUT **the** Russian sound system (*or* phonology)
- Russian syntax OR Russian word order [no article]
- Russian semantics BUT **the** Russian mentality
- Russian vocabulary BUT **the** Russian lexicon

Comment: You could also say "I'm having trouble with the Russian grammar of this sentence", which sounds much more natural than without "the".

Answer (score -1):

The definite article is required as you are talking about **the specific grammar** of **the specific language out of those three grammar**

This said, it should be...

> Let's discuss or talk about **the** English grammar.

It can also go *without* any article if you are talking about English grammar in general. *Ah, I just said it!*

Comment: Not in Anglo-American English. We speak of *the* English/German/&c grammar only if *grammar* has the sense of *grammar-book*. *Grammar* in the sense "body (or study) of grammatical rules" is like *law* or *medicine* or *sport*: where a determiner is called for, the proper adjective alone is adequate.

Comment: @StoneyB I thought if there is an option of three languages as asked in question, it'd take the article. I've come across such instances where it took an article and the matter wasn't about the book.

Comment: Can you provide an instance? The first 30 hits I find on "the English grammar" in Google all either a) occur in  attributives (*Answer the English grammar questions*) in which the article is governed by the noun which *English grammar* modifies or b) derive from non-native speakers. Is there any possibility that this is an Indian English usage? Note that I was careful to qualify my comment as concerned with Anglo usage; I am not sufficiently knowledgeable about Indian English to judge where the line between learner error and regional Standard should be drawn.

Comment: @StoneyB yes I've heard from a non native but learned person. Anyway another instance *CSLI was responsible for building the English grammar for the deep-processing component of Verbmobil, which utilized a semantic transfer approach, requiring both parsing and generation...*

Comment: Aha! In that case you are not speaking of *English grammar* as we ordinarily intend the phrase--the grammar of the natural language--but of a non-linguistic artifact which emulates 'English grammar' in order to produce or translate English-language utterances: the 'English grammar' *module* or *subprogram* or *library*.